# A polite way to say " this person"

Tags: second-person-pronouns

What do I say in Japanese when I'm trying to imply, "This is my dad", "These are my parents", "This is my friend(female)" or "This is my manager"?

I don't think using `これ` is polite, nor will `彼` be appropriate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The alternative to これ　in polite Japanese conversation is こちら (you should find it in most 初級Japanese text books on how to introduce yourself.)

To implement this （borrowing Dono's answer） I would say:

> こちらは私の父です。 This is my father.
>    こちらは私の両親です。These are my parents.
>   こちらは私の友達、由美子です。This is my friend Yumiko.
>   こちらは私のマネジャー（上司）です。This is my manager.

You can even use this to introduce yourself on the phone:

> [あの..]こちらはABCのVenkatesh Kumarですが[いつもお世話になっております。]

The stop gap alternative to referring to people by pronouns (he/she/you etc) is to use their name.  You would attach the suffix (さん　etc) according to the relationship between you, your 相手 and your colleague.friend etc.

Answer (score 5):

You do not need anything. Just list their title and add desu.

- This is my dad: 父です or オヤジです。
- These are my parents: 両親です。
- This is my friend (female): 友達です。
- This is my manager: マネジャー（上司）です。

Comment: I think the OP was looking for an alternative to これ: What about introducing the person with こちらは私の[ちちです　etc].

Comment: @user1205935, "use nothing" is an alternative, but the space deixis is lost. That's not the case with こちら.

Comment: @Tim:  Please put that as a separate answer (or I will).

Answer (score 4):

**こちらは** 田中さんです。(He is Mr.Tanaka) こちらは is polite way to say he or she